# how to change teraterm terminal input size?

Tags: terminal, teraterm

I'm new to use tera-term.

I want to write the long string in the tera-term terminal.

but when I type string, it accepts just 256bytes.

I try to change the setup, but I couldn't find about it.

If somebody knows about it then please help. Thank you.

Comment: The input-limitation comes from whatever program you are running in TeraTerm.

Comment: I run same program on two computer . And one can accept more than 256 bytes but another cannot accept more than 256 bytes.. so I think it is problem of tera term setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The maximum length of a string is 511." found at: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/syntax/types.html

Maybe you can block your string into smaller batches and send them that way.

Hope that helps!